# Clone closest row from a href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that is supposed to duplicate the row that I specify. My table is made dynamically so I am not able to define an id. I want to be able to click a button on the specified row and find the closest tr to duplicate.

The code that is supposed to duplicate is:

```
 function cloneRow()
 {
   var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // find row to copy
   var table = document.getElementById("ScannedItems");
   var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
   clone.id = "newID";
   table.appendChild(clone);
 }
```

I am needing to change `var row = $(this).closest('tr');` to something else but I don't know what to change it to so I can get the closest `tr` from the `a href` that is clicked.

Or just duplicate the same row that the a is clicked on.

The a href looks like this

```
<a onclick='cloneRow();'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' style='padding-right:15px;'>
```

I know the question is not explained very well... I made a jsFiddle for refrence of what I'm talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/KSCLC/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ankr/N6ykr/

Here's the code

**Javascript**

```
var $table = $('#myTable');

$table.on('click', 'a.clone', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').clone();

    // Do stuff to $tr here

    $table.append($tr);
});

$table.on('click', 'a.remove', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove()
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="clone">Clone 1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="remove">Remove 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="clone">Clone 2</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="remove">Remove 2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="clone">Clone 3</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="remove">Remove 3</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what word would you use instead of `clone` to `delete` the row?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/remove/ - Also I have updated my answer and fiddle to include remove.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. in the context of your function, `this` represents `Window`
You need to do something like this:

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="copynode">copynode</a>
```

Javascript

```
$('#copynode').on('click', function(e) { // attach the event click on the element #copynode
 $(this).closest('tr').clone().appendTo('#ScannedItems'); // find the closest tr, clone it, and append it on the ScannedItems table
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: A. When I leave the `href='#'` in the a the page loads another page. B. When I take it out nothing happens.

Comment: See the `preventDefault` documentation http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/